Include Single Directory Component as a library
The JS and CSS files associated with a Single Directory Component are automatically included when the component is used in a Twig file.
However, we have a JS component that renders HTML initially defined in a Single Directory Component that isn't included in the initial page load. Therefore, the associated styles are not being loaded.
Is there any way we can set a SDC as a dependency of another SDC without using it in the Twig file (like libraryOverrides in the component definition for regular libraries)?

If you're using the core SDC module you should be able to use 'librariesOverrides' and something like:
libraryOverrides:
  dependencies:    
    - core/components.mytheme--mycomponent

